# Error inserting multiple rows in a table

Tags: sql, cursor, error

I am trying to insert values using the query below in a table

```
insert into mytable (geom)
values( (SELECT new_york_city_political_utm.geom
         FROM pointutm 
         join new_york_city_political_utm
         on st_within( pointutm.geom , new_york_city_political_utm.geom)));
```

but I encountered an error:

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: While there is a geometry column involved, this is more of a pure SQL question. Please be sure to research the error message *before* asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `values ()`, you can only specify data for a single new row. You would need to use a different SQL query, omiting the `values`

```
insert into mytable (geom)
SELECT new_york_city_political_utm.geom
FROM pointutm 
join new_york_city_political_utm
on st_within( pointutm.geom , new_york_city_political_utm.geom);
```